# Почему не работает fill в openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

При переходе на другой компьютер перестал работать fill у openpyxl.
Вот простой пример, у которого fill не работает, а value работает

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A2'].fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="FFFF0000")
ws['A1'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF0000', end_color='FFFF0000', fill_type='solid')
ws['A1'].value = 'lol'
wb.save('lol.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Причём значение "lol" встаёт в ячейку, а заливка не встаёт.

Вот список всех библиотек и версий

| Заголовок | Ещё заголовок |
| --- | --- |
| et-xmlfile | 1.1.0 |
| openpyxl | 3.1.2 |
| pathlib | 1.0.1 |
| pillow | 10.2.0 |
| pip | 23.3.2 |

Я уже голову сломал. Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: А если добавить заливку, сохранить, затем добавить значение в ячейку и снова сохранить?